# rails unit/test get ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

there is a easy dependencies in my exercise_project

`patients belongs_to location

location has_many patients`

my `patients_controller.rb` file

```
 class PatientsController < ApplicationController
    def location
       @location = Location.find(params[:id])
       place = @location.id
       @patients = Patient.where(:location_id => place)
    end

    def index
        @patients = Patient.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order('id DESC')

        respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @patients }
    end
end
```

***others are same with which generate by rails default***

my `patients#index` file

```
<table>
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= patient.name %> </td>
    <td><%= patient.birthday %> </td>
    <td><%= patient.gender %></td>
    <td><%= medical_record(patient.id) %></td>
    <td><%= patient.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to(patient.location.name, location_path(patient.location)) %> </td>
    <td><%= patient.viewed_count %></td>
   </tr>
     <td><%= link_to 'Show', patient_path(patient) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_patient_path(patient) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', patient_path(patient), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are YOU SURE?' %></td>
 <% end %>
</table>
    <%= link_to "create patient", new_patient_path %><hr>
    <%= link_to "Locations", locations_path %>
```

and I write a unit/test for the controller

```
require 'test_helper'

class PatientsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @patient = patients(:one)
    @location = locations(:one)
    @patient.location_id = @location.id
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:patients)
  end

end
```

When I run the test, it returns
`` 1) Error:

test_should_get_index(PatientsControllerTest):

ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass ``

I do know it must be the `location` method in the controller that makes it, but I can't find  a way to solve this.
How could write the right test for this controller?

---------------------updated------------------------------------
I change it to this

```
require 'test_helper'

class PatientsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @patient = patients(:one)
    @location = locations(:one)
    @patient.location_id = @location.id
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :location
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:patients)
  end

end
```

and get `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"patients", :action=>"location"}`

my `routes.rb`

```
Patients::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations  
  resources :patients  

  root to: "locations#index"    
  match "patients/location/:id", :to => "patients#location", :as => :location_patients  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get :location
```

...(and more text because stackoverflow requires 30 character answers.)

Comment: thanks for answering... but I still didn't solve it, I've updated the question.

Comment: I got it, I will fix it myself